# Share generic between traits

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have two traits

```
trait Base[A]

trait SometimesUsedWithBase[A] {
    this: Base[A] =>
}
```

I then use these with a class

```
class StringThing extends Base[String] with SometimesUsedWithBase[String]
```

It would be great if I didn't have to define **SometimesUsedWithBase**'s type, and instead it somehow understands that it's using the type defined in **Base** so that it looks like:

```
class StringThing extends Base[String] with SometimesUsedWithBase
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this.

```
trait Base[A] {
  type BaseType = A
}

trait SometimesUsedWithBase {
  this: Base[_] =>
  def someFunction: BaseType
}

class StringThing extends Base[String] with SometimesUsedWithBase {
  def someFunction: String = ""
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me, especially since they are tied together anyways. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently if you add a parameter to someFunction that is of type BaseType, you'll get errors about Covariant and Contravariant positions..